# Why Resteasy bean validation doesn't work?

Tags: spring-boot, resteasy, bean-validation

Here is my setup:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAX-RS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

my controller:

```
@Path("/v1")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserRestService {

...

    @POST
    @Path("/users")
    public RestResponse<UserListItemRestDto> createUser(@Valid CreateUserRestDto createUserRestDto) {
...
```

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Data
public class CreateUserRestDto {

    @NotNull(message = "version cannot be null")
    private Long version;

    @NotNull(message = "name cannot be null")
    private String name;
}
```

Requests that the endpoint accepts right now:

- empty object: {}
- {"name": "something"} : version is also "NotNull" but ignores it.

Requests that fails the validation:

- {"version":"asd"} : this time I get `Unrecognized field ... not marked as ignorable`

Why is that it only "see" one property? Am I using something wrong?

I managed to handle exceptions with a custom class that implements `ExceptionMapper<Exception>`

Am I supposed to make a custom Deserializer or a RequestFilter?

By the way I did just as the JBOSS docs said and nothing worked.

Comment: Have you tried adding the dependency for `org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-validator-provider`?